# Order JIRA filter by position of the tasks in the backlog

Tags: agile, jira

I have a custom filter defined by this query

```
project = ProjectName AND status in ("In Progress", Open, Reopened) AND assignee in (currentUser()) AND sprint in openSprints() AND sprint not in futureSprints() ORDER BY updated DESC
```

As you can see, this filter gets all open tasks of the current active sprint of a specific project.

I'd like to order by the position of the tasks in the backlog list but I can't find any relevant information about this in the JIRA documentation, not in the [fields reference](https://confluence.atlassian.com/jirasoftwarecloud/advanced-searching-fields-reference-764478339.html) nor in the [functions reference](https://confluence.atlassian.com/jirasoftwarecloud/advanced-searching-functions-reference-764478342.html)

Just to be clear, I don't want to order them by `Priority` or `Level` but really by the order they appear in the backlog page.

There is another tricky detail is that (I think) sub-tasks don't actually have a positions in the backlog because they are simply not part of the backlog. Their parent tasks however are.

so to sum-up:

1. Is it possible (and how) to order by task's position in the backlog?
2. Is it possible (and how) to order sub-tasks by their parent-task's position in the backlog?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The attribute you are looking for is Rank, so you should add "order by RANK asc"

For the subtasks you need scriptrunner to make a query like this:
project = XXX and issueFunction in subtasksOf("issuetype = story order by RANK asc")

Comment: That's right, `RANK` is what I was looking for. I just want to add that I actually don't need to use `scriptrunner` because, by default, sub-tasks appear right under their parent tasks in the result list and they do still appear even if the parent task is not assigned to me. This is exactly what I wanted